# Selenium PHP - findElement by xpath, complex xpath not working

Tags: php, xml, selenium, xpath

Dears,

I'm facing a problem with the following xpath which returns no element if $pos is greater than 1.

> note that there is more than 1 div[@class="panel-heading"] in
>   form[contains(@action, "/myaction?")]

```
$this->webdriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('//form[contains(@action, "/myaction?")]//div[@class="panel-heading"][' . $pos . ']//a[contains(@onclick, "do_something")]'))->click();
```

Any idea what's wrong with my xpath ?

Thanks in advance,
Lionel

Comment: The xpath seems ok.Please add the html snippet of the form if possible.Have you tried the xpath's in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have only one single link with that action, search only for
 `//a[contains(@onclick, "do_something")]` and see if you identify the `do_something` that make is unique.
Avoid using `[number]` because it can break easy if any of the abode div's is gone.

If you get issues when `$pos` is greater than one means that the `div` which gets this condition is not at the same level with any other `div`.

Comment: Every div[@class="panel-heading"] are on the same level in the DOM tree.  And for each, there is only 1 a[contains(@onclick, "do_something")] bellow.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `()` if you are using index in your `xpath` as below :-

```
$this->webdriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('(//form[contains(@action, "/myaction?")]//div[@class="panel-heading"])[' . $pos . ']//a[contains(@onclick, "do_something")]'))->click();
```